# Access Control List when running script from crontab

Tags: permissions, cron, acl

hoping someone has come across this before,

I am using ACLs to allow one user (user1) to write files into a location in another user's home directory (user2). For manual usage, this is working as expected (e.g. I can cp / mv / unlink / touch from user1 session to user2 location, etc.)

I have a node script which automates this. When I run the node script manually (as user1), all works as expected. However, when it is run from user1's crontab, the step which copies the files to the user2 location fails (silently).

I know the script works as intended, and I know the crontab *is* running the script (all other steps are completed). From looking at syslog, it seems the job is being run with the correct user (user1), so the only thing I can think of now is that the ACLs aren't respected for some reason when the script runs from crontab?

I'm wondering if anyone has come across this before -- is there an obvious step I might be missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using the acl in your script?

Comment: I'm just performing a copy between the accounts (an exec to native cp, & a copy method from an npm module (fs-extra)). 

To be clear though, if I manually run the script (i.e. `node myscript.js`) it works -- the problem is only when the script is run from crontab (all other steps in the script work except the copy, so I know it's not a problem with cron running the script). I have also ruled out a bad file paths (tried with hard-coding absolute paths).

Maybe I'm way off thinking its related to the ACLs, but I've ruled out just about everything else--I'm going for the long-shots now :)

Comment: I infer, from your use of ACLs, that `user2` has an encrypted `HOME` directory. If so, `~user2` is mounted only when `user2` is logged in. Try copying the file to somewhere else, e.g. `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/`. If my inference is bad, so's my suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that's not it. But thanks anyway.